# Retry failed API call to another origin in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, http, rxjs, observable

I want to implement a logic of retrying an API call to another origin if the call to current origin failed.
I want it to be handled in the service layer, for not to implement this logic in each component.

For example, I have such function in endpoint service

```
 getAll(): Observable<IssueListItem[]> {
        let endpointUrl = `${this.apiConnectionService.getApiUrl()}api/Issues`;
        return this.http.get<IssueListItem[]>(endpointUrl, { headers: this.dataService.requestHeaders })
            .pipe(retryOtherApi(this.apiConnectionService),
                catchError(error => this.handleError(error)));
    }
```

The consumer of this function looks like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.issuesEndpointService.getAll()
        .subscribe(_ => this.issues = _);
}
```

And I whant it know nothing about retry logic.

So, I tried to create an operator 'retryOtherApi' where I switch an origin to another one.

```
export function retryOtherApi(apiConnectionService: ApiConnectionService) {
    const maxRetry = apiConnectionService.apiOriginsCount;

    return (src: Observable<any>) => src.pipe(
        retryWhen(_ => {
            return interval().pipe(
                flatMap(count => {
                    console.log('switch to: ' + apiConnectionService.getApiUrl())
                    apiConnectionService.switchToOther();
                    return count === maxRetry ? throwError("Giving up") : of(count);
                })
            );
        })
    );
}
```

Switching works, but unfortunately, the whole getAll function is not called and it retries n times with the same old URL.

So the question is how to implement common retry to other API logic if the current API become unavailable.

If to rephrase the question to the more common case, it becomes like how to recall HTTP endpoint with other params if the current one failed.

Comment: did you [read this](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html)?

Answer (score 0):

```
public getAll(): Observable<IssueListItem[]> {
    let call = () => {
        let endpointUrl = `${this.apiConnectionService.getApiUrl()}api/Issues`;
        return this.http.get<IssueListItem[]>(endpointUrl, { headers: this.dataService.requestHeaders })
    };

    return <Observable<IssueListItem[]>>call()
        .pipe(
            retryOtherApi(this.apiConnectionService, () => call()),
            catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
        );
}
```

And here is a retry operator:

```
export function retryOtherApi(apiConnectionService: ApiConnectionService, recall: () => Observable<any>) {
    const maxRetry = apiConnectionService.apiOriginsCount;
    let count = 0;

    let retryLogic = (src: Observable<any>) => src.pipe(
        catchError(e => {
            if (e.status === 0) {
                apiConnectionService.switchToOther();
                console.log('switch to: ' + apiConnectionService.getApiUrl())
                return count++ === maxRetry ? throwError(e) : retryLogic(recall());
            } else {
                return throwError(e);
            }
        }));

    return retryLogic;
}
```

It works, but:

1. Now I need to implement logic for other threads not to switch api
   simultaneously.
2. Have some problems with TS typecasting, that is
   why I hardcoded type before return.